# page break a specific portion of the page

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc-3, browser, printing

I am trying to take a specific portion of the page to the next page keeping the rest of the page elements after that potion on the first page, let me explain it with a figure

[image]

i want to take the `tr` with `class=nextpage` to the next page and keep the rest of the page as it is so that the final print would look like

[image]

is it possible to achieve? or do i have to consider some other options like iText sharp (though i dont know how would i use it too).. please help me find a way

Answer (score 1):

So normally you would write the following CSS to get the element on the next page and be done:

```
.nextPage {
  page-break-before: always;
}
```

But this only works for block elements. You could add `display:block` to your CSS class, but that would change the formatting of the table row. Maybe the best thing to do is to wrap the contents of the first cell in the table row in a div, which is a block element:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="nextPage"></div></td><td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @ Annie the div elements with class=`nextPage` will be shifted to the next page, how can i then format them into a table?

Comment: If you look at the example HTML, you can put the <div> elements inside the <td> elements. So they are still in the table. It's just that part of the table (the part starting with the div) is now on a new page when it prints.

Comment: @ Annie nope nothing happens the `td` having values wrapped in `div class="nextPage">sdasdsa</div>,/td>` remains on the same page

Comment: here is the gist of my view source it quite messy but you will spot the tr with div elements having the class `pagebreakclass` https://gist.github.com/2516367